# python - finding a motif - input: a .txt file with 10 seqs and 10 motifs

Tags: python-3.6, brute-force

When I run my BruteForce function with only one input it works and the result is correct.

```
def BruteForce(s, t):
    occurrences = []
    for i in range(len(s)-len(t)+1): # loop over alignment
        match = True
        for j in range(len(t)): # loop over characters
            if s[i+j] != t[j]:  # compare characters
                match = False   # mismatch
                break
        if match:   # allchars matched
            occurrences.append(i)

    print(occurrences)
```

t = 'CAACTTCCA'

s = 'GACAACTTCCAACTTCCAACTTCCCGTCCCAACTTCACAACTTCGGCCCAACTTCCATGCAACTTCACCATCAACTTCGCTCGAAGCTGCCTTCCACTCCAACTTCACAACTTCCTCAACTTCCTCACCAACTTCAGCAACTTCTCTAGGGCCAACTTCCAACTTCTCAACTTCTCAACTTCCAACTTCCGACAACTTCTCCTGGCAACTTCCAACTTCCAACTTCAATACAACTTCGCAGACAACTTCCGCAACTTCGAACAACTTCCAACTTCCCCAACTTCCAACTTCCAACTTCGCCAACTTCCAACTTCCAACTTCCCAACTTCAGATAGCAACTTCGATCTTACACAACTTCACGCAACTTCTCCAACTTCCAACTTCTGTGCAACTTCTCTGAACAACTTCCTCAACTTCCAACTTCGCAACTTCCCCAACTTCCTCAACTTCATGCAACTTCGAGGCAACTTCCCAACTTCGCAACTTCCTATTCCCAACTTCTGTGGCAACTTCTCAACTTCTGGACAACTTCTATGCCCAACTTCACAACTTCCCCAACTTCTTTACAACTTCGACAACTTCATCAACTTCTAGTCAACTTCTGGTCCAACTTCCAACTTCCCCAACTTCCAAAGTGCCGCAACTTCGTAACAACTTCACGCGCTCAACTTCAACCAACTTCTTTTCCCGCAACTTCGCAACTTCACAACTTCTAATCAACTTCCAACTTCGGATCAACTTCCAACTTCGCCAACTTCCAACTTCCAACTTCTCCAGGGACAACTTCAAGTACAACTTCCAACTTCGCAACTTCACAACTTCCCAACTTCGCAACTTCTACACGCAACTTCCAACTTCTGGTCCCAACTTCATCAACTTCAGTCAACTTC'

BruteForce(s, t)

[2, 9, 48, 152, 175, 205, 212, 261, 277, 284, 300, 307, 370, 410, 607, 623, 717, 735, 751, 758, 792, 844]

But when I use it in the following loop it returns nothing! I have used the print() to see if it reads the strings and motifs from the input_2.txt file and it does but it returns an empty list of occurrences [].

```
with open('input_2.txt', 'r') as input_2:
    nt = input_2.readline() #nt is the no of strings+motifs in 1st line
    nt = int(nt) #in this case it is 10

    for i in range(nt):
        s = input_2.readline()
        print(s)
        t = input_2.readline()
        print(t)
        BruteForce(s, t)
```

Could you please let me know what changes are needed here? Many thanks, Beeta

input_2.txt

10

GACAACTTCCAACTTCCAACTTCCCGTCCCAACTTCACAACTTCGGCCCAACTTCCATGCAACTTCACCATCAACTTCGCTCGAAGCTGCCTTCCACTCCAACTTCACAACTTCCTCAACTTCCTCACCAACTTCAGCAACTTCTCTAGGGCCAACTTCCAACTTCTCAACTTCTCAACTTCCAACTTCCGACAACTTCTCCTGGCAACTTCCAACTTCCAACTTCAATACAACTTCGCAGACAACTTCCGCAACTTCGAACAACTTCCAACTTCCCCAACTTCCAACTTCCAACTTCGCCAACTTCCAACTTCCAACTTCCCAACTTCAGATAGCAACTTCGATCTTACACAACTTCACGCAACTTCTCCAACTTCCAACTTCTGTGCAACTTCTCTGAACAACTTCCTCAACTTCCAACTTCGCAACTTCCCCAACTTCCTCAACTTCATGCAACTTCGAGGCAACTTCCCAACTTCGCAACTTCCTATTCCCAACTTCTGTGGCAACTTCTCAACTTCTGGACAACTTCTATGCCCAACTTCACAACTTCCCCAACTTCTTTACAACTTCGACAACTTCATCAACTTCTAGTCAACTTCTGGTCCAACTTCCAACTTCCCCAACTTCCAAAGTGCCGCAACTTCGTAACAACTTCACGCGCTCAACTTCAACCAACTTCTTTTCCCGCAACTTCGCAACTTCACAACTTCTAATCAACTTCCAACTTCGGATCAACTTCCAACTTCGCCAACTTCCAACTTCCAACTTCTCCAGGGACAACTTCAAGTACAACTTCCAACTTCGCAACTTCACAACTTCCCAACTTCGCAACTTCTACACGCAACTTCCAACTTCTGGTCCCAACTTCATCAACTTCAGTCAACTTC

CAACTTCCA

ATTGTGTATCGCTATGTATCGTGTATCGGATTTTGTATCGTGTATCGGTGTATCGTGTATCGTGTATCGTATCACTGTATCGTTGTATCGTAGCGTTGTATCGTAATGTATCGCTCTGTATCGTGTATCGGGTTTGTATCGATGTGTATCGCTGTATCGGTGTATCGGTGTATCGCTTGTATCGACAGCGCTTGTATCGTGTATCGACCTGTATCGGTGTATCGTGTATCGAATGTATCGTTGTATCGAATTGTGTATCGTGTATCGTGTATCGTGTATCGTATGTATCGACTGTATCGCTGTATCGTAGCCTGTATCGTGTATCGGTGTATCGGTGTATCGGCGTGTATCGAATGTATCGTTGTATCGCTGTATCGTGTGCTGTGTATCGGTGTATCGACCCGTTGTATCGTGTATCGTGGGTAAGTGTATCGTTGTATCGTAGTGTATCGTGTATCGTGTATCGTCATGGTATTGTATCGTTATAGCTGTATCGCTCGGCTGTATCGTATGTATCGTGTATCGTGTATCGCATGTATCGGTGTATCGCTGTATCGACCATGTATCGTGTATCGGTGTATCGATGTATCGCTTCCATTAGAAATGTATCGTATGTATCGTGTATCGCTGTATCGTTTGTATCGCATGTATCGATTGTGTATCGTGTATCGTTGTATCGTGTATCGTGTATCGTTGTATCGTAATAACGATGTATCGAATGATGTATCGTTGTGATGTATCGTGTATCGACTGTATCGATGTATCGGGTTGTATCGTGTATCGTGTATCGTAGATGTATCGAGAGCCATTGTATCGCCTTGTATCGCGTGTATCGGTGTGTATCGTTTGTATCGTGTTTGAATGTATCGCTGTATCG

TGTATCGTG

TTTCAGCGTGTTTGGCTTTCAGCACTACTTTCAGCGGTTTCAGCTTTTTCAGCTTTTCAGCTATTTTCAGCTTTCAGCCATCTTTCAGCCCAGGTTTCAGCTGTTTCAGCTTTCAGCGAGTTTCAGCTTTCAGCGCGGGGATTTCAGCGTATTTCAGCGACATTTCAGCAGTTTCAGCTGGAGTGAAGCCGTTTCAGCGCTTTTCAGCACCATTTCAGCTAGTAGGTTTCAGCTTTTCAGCCTTTTCAGCTTTCAGCTATTTCAGCTCTAGAAGTCGTTTCAGCTTTCAGCTTCCTTTTCAGCTTTCAGCTTTCAGCCTTTCAGCTTTCAGCAAACTTTCAGCGATTTCAGCTTTCAGCTTTCAGCTTTCAGCTTTCAGCATTTCAGCTTTCAGCCGTTTTCAGCGACTCTTTCAGCGTTTCAGCTTTCAGCTGATCGTTTTCAGCTTTTCAGCCGGTTTCAGCGAAAGTTGGTCTTTTCAGCCAAATTTTCAGCTTTCAGCTTTCAGCGTTTCAGCTTTTCAGCCATTTCAGCCTATTTTCAGCAATCTTTCAGCAATTTTCAGCGCAATTTCAGCCAAAATTTCAGCATTTCAGCTTTCAGCGTAGTTTCAGCTTTCAGCTGAGCCTTTCAGCTTTTCAGCTCTCTTTTCAGCTTTCAGCGATTTCAGCCTTTTCAGCGCTTTCAGCACCACGCCTTTCAGCTTTCAGCTTTTCAGCCTTTCAGCCTATTTTCAGCGGTTTCAGCGTTTCAGCTTTCAGCACTTTCAGCTTTCAGCTTTTCAGCGGAAGGTTTTCAGCA

TTTCAGCTT

AGCATCCGACTGCATCCGTGCATCCGACGGCATCCGGCATCCGCAGCATCCGCACAGCCGCATCCGAGCCCGCATCCGAAGCATCCGGCATCCGGGCATCCGGCCGCATCCGGCATCCGGGCATCCGTGCATCCGGCATCCGTGTGCATCCGGCATCCGGGGTGCTTGCATCCGCGCATCCGTGCATCCGCGCATCCGGCATCCGCAGTCCGCATCCGCGCATCCGGCATCCGAGCATCCGTATTCGCATCCGTCGAGCATCCGTACGTCGCATCCGTGCATCCGGGAGAGGCATCCGGGCATCCGCGCATCCGGTGGACTATAACGCGCATCCGGCGAGCATCCGCCGCGGCATCCGTGCATCCGGTACGGCATCCGGGCTGAGGCATCCGCTCCCGGGGCATCCGCGGCGCATCCGCACGCGCATCCGGCATCCGAGCATCCGTTGCATCCGGAGCATCCGTAGCATCCGATAGCATCCGCAAGCTTGCATCCGGCATCCGCTACAGCATCCGGTGGCATCCGAAGCATCCGCGCATCCGCGGATTGCATCCGCACACGGCATCCGTAGCATCCGTGCATCCGGAGTGCATCCGCCGGGCGCATCCGCTGCATCCGCAGCGCATCCGAGCATCCGATCTTGCATCCGGCATCCGGGAATGCATCCGGGACTGCATCCGGTCTTAAGGGTGCATCCGAATGCATCCGCTGTAGCATCCGGCATCCGAGTAAGCATCCGAGTTCTGCATCCGGAAGCAGCATCCGGCATCCGGACACCAGCATCCGCGCATCCGGGGCGAGCATCCGAGCATCCGGCATCCGGGGCAAGTGGCATCCGGCATCCGTCGTGCATCCGGGCATCCGAA

GCATCCGGC

GACGAGCTGACGAGCGTGACGAGCAGGCGACGAGCGACGAGCATGCGGTGACGAGCGGACGAGCGACGACGAGCGCGGACGAGCGACGAGCGGACGAGCTCCGACGAGCGACGAGCACGACGAGCGCCCGACGAGCGACGAGCATGATGACGAGCGACGAGCTTAGACGAGCATGCTGACGAGCTGACGAGCTGACGAGCTCGTACATCGACGAGCGGACGAGCAGCCCGATAAGCCTTCGACGAGCTGACGAGCCACGACGAGCGACGAGCGACGAGCGGACGAGCGGGACGAGCGTCGGACGAGCGGACGAGCAGGACGAGCACCTCAATCGACGAGCTGACGAGCGGACGAGCCGACGAGCTGAACTGAAGGACGAGCCTACGTTCTAACGTGCCGTCACTGACGAGCGACGAGCGGACGAGCGATGGACGAGCTGACGAGCGCAGGACGAGCGAGAAGGCTGACGAGCAGACGAGCTGACGAGCTCGACGAGCAGACGAGCGGACGAGCTTTGATAAGACGAGCACGTCGACGAGCCTCGTGACGAGCTGACGAGCGACGAGCTAGACGAGCGACGAGCTGACGAGCGACGAGCACTAAACGCGACGAGCTCGACGACGAGCATGGACGAGCGACGAGCTAGGACGAGCGGCGACGAGCAGACGAGCGACGAGCTGACGAGCTTATAGACGAGCCTGACGACGAGCCAAGACGAGCGACGAGCGGACGAGCGACGAGCACGACGAGCCGACGAGCCGCGGACGAGCCGTAGACGAGCCAATCATTAAGACGAGCCGACGAGCCATTTGGGGACGAGCCTCCTCGACGAGCCATAAGACGAGCTGACGAGCCATGACGAGCATGCCCGACGAGC

GACGAGCGA

GAGGACCCCGGACCCCTGGACCCCAGGACCCCGACGGTGGGGCGGACCCCGAGAAGGACCCCTGGACCCCCGCAGGACCCCTTTATCGGACCCCGGACCCCGGACCCCCGGACCCCGGCTGGACCCCGTCGTAAGGACCCCGAATCGGACCCCTAGGACCCCAGGGACCCCTCCCCGGTTGGACCCCCTGGACCCCCTTGAGAGGGACCCCGGACCCCACGCCGTGCTTAAGGACCCCACTATGGACCCCATACGGACCCCGGACCCCGATCAGAGCGACCAGGACCCCCGGCCTGGACCCCTCGGACCCCAGAAGGACCCCTCGGACCCCTGGACCCCGGACCCCACAGGGACCCCGGACCCCTAGCCGCGGTGGACCCCCGGACCCCCGCAGATGGGGACCCCTCATGCGGACCCCCTGACGGACCCCTGGACCCCCGGGACCCCCAGGGACCCCATTTCGAGGACCCCATGGGGACCCCAAGCTGGACCCCGGACCCCTGGGACCCCCGGACCCCGGACCCCGGACCCCATAGGACCCCCGTTTGTTGCCATGGACCCCTTGGGACCCCGAGTCGGACCCCGGACCCCCAGGACCCCACAGGACCCCGGGACCCCGGACCCCATCGATCGGACCCCGGACCCCGGACCCCTACGGACCCCGCTAAGGGACCCCGGACCCCGTGGACCCCCACGGACCCCTAGGACCCCGGGACCCCGGACCCCGGACCCCAGTTGGACCCCCCTTAGGACCCCAGGACCCCACATGAGGACCCCGGGACCCCGGGACCCCTGGACCCCTGGACCCC

GGACCCCGG

AAACCTTCGGACCTTCGTACCTTCGACCTTCGTGAAACCTTCGGACCTTCGTGACCTTCGGGTGACCTTCGGGTACTCACCTTCGGCACCTTCGTATACCTTCGAGACCTTCGCTGGACTGTAAACCTTCGATCGTTATTTTCTACCTTCGCACACCTTCGACCTTCGAGCCGAACCTTCGGACTGGCCTCACCTTCGATCACCTTCGACCTTCGAACCTTCGACCTTCGACCATACCTTCGACCTTCGGACCTTCGGACCTTCGCACCTTCGAACCTTCGCCACCTTCGACCTTCGAACCTTCGGTGGGCCACCTTCGTTACCTTCGAACCTTCGGGCACCTTCGACCTTCGGCTTACACCTTCGGACCTTCGATGACTGACCTTCGAAACCTTCGACCTTCGACCTTCGATTCCACACCTTCGACCTTCGACACCTTCGACCTTCGCGTTCACCTTCGACCTTCGACCTTCGGGCCAATACCTTCGACCTTCGGCCTAATACCAACCTTCGAACCTTCGAACCTTCGGGTGACCTTCGGACCTTCGCGCACACCTTCGCACTTACCTTCGACCTTCGGTGACCTTCGACCTTCGTGCACCTTCGCGTCTCACCTTCGCACCTTCGTTACCTTCGAACCTTCGACCTTCGACAACCTTCGTACCTTCGCTACCTTCGGGAACCTTCGATGTCCTACCTTCGACCTTCGCGACCTTCGACCTTCGTAACCTTCGAACCTTCGACCACCTTCGAACCTTCGAAGGAAGGACCTTCGAATCATTACCTTCGTTACCTTCGTAGTACCTTCGCCGACCTTCGGACCTTAACCTTCGTGA

ACCTTCGAC

AAGTGGTATTCCCAAAAAGATATTCCCGTTATTCCCGCTATAAATATTCCCAACTGTTTATTCCCACTTATTCCCGTATTCCCGTATTCCCCGGGCCTTTTATTCCCCATTCTATTCCCGTATTCCCATATTCCCACTTATTCCCCTATTCCCATATTCCCTATTCCCTATTCCCGTAAGTATTCCCCCCCTTATTCCCCCATTTGTCCATATTCCCTCAATATTCCCTATTCCCCTATTCCCGCTTCCCCAGTCTATCCCAAATTGTATTCCCAATATTCCCCTTTATTCCCTTTATTCCCGTATTCCCTATTCCCGTGGCTATTCCCCCGACGTTATTCCCTCTATATTCCCGTCTCAAAGTATTCCCTTATTCCCAGTATTCCCATTCGCCTGGTATTCCCGTATTCCCGGTATTCCCGTTTATTCCCATCTATTCCCATTATTCCCTGGTATTCCCGCTATTCCCGCAACGGTATTCCCTATTCCCTATTCCCGTATTCCCAATATTCCCTTCCTATTCCCGTATTCCCTAGCTATTCCCATATTCCCGATATTCCCTATTCCCGTATTCCCTATTCCCTTATTCCCTATTCCCTAGTTATTCCCAAACAGGCTATTCCCTATTCCCTATTCCCATATTCCCTTATTCCCTACGTATTCCCTCTTAAAAATATTATTCCCCTATTCCCTATTCCCGTATTCCCCGAAAGTATTCCCCCATATTCCCAATTATATTCCCGGTATTCCCCCGTATTCCCTATTCCCTTATTCCCATATTCCCATATTCCCAAAGTTTATTCCCGTATTCCCCACTATTCCCATAGATTATTCCCTATTCCCTATTCCCTTATTCCCCTATTCCCTATTCCCTTATTCCCGTATTCCCAGTTTATTCCC

TATTCCCTA

GAAAGGATAAAGGATGTCAAAGGATGCAGATATAAAGGATAAAGGATACAAAGGATTAAGTATGTCCGAAAAAGGATAAAGGATTAAAAGGATCGCTGAACCTTACACAAAGGATAGTGAACAAAGGATTCAATAAAAGGATAAAGGATCAAAGGATCAAAAGGATACAAAGGATGCCGATGAAAGGATAAAGGATCTAAAGGATAAAGGATGAGAAAGGATTGGAAAGGATTATGAGATCAAAGGATAAAGGATGGTGTAAAAGCTAAAGGATTCGGCAAAGGATAAAGGATTAAAGGATAAAAAGGATAAAGGATGAAAGGATCCGCAGGGACCAGCAAAAGGATAAAGGATCGAATGGGTAAGAAAGGATCAAAGGATGAAAAAGGATTACTAAAGGATAAAGGATCCTGAAAGGATTACAAAGGATCTTAAAAGGATTCGGAAAGGATCCATAGGAAAAGGATAAAGGATCGCGAAAGGATAAAGGATTAAAGGATAAAGGATAAAAGGATTCAAAGGATAAAGGATAGACAAGGGAGAAAGGATGCAAAGGATGAAAGGATAAAGGATAAAGGATAAAGGATTAGGTTAAAGGATCGAAAGGATCCAAAGAGAGCGAAAAGGATGAGGACGAAAGGATCAAAGGATCCAAAGGATCAAAGGATAAAGGATTGCGATGGAAAGGATGTCAAAGGATCACCAAAGGATAAAGGATAATAAAGGATAAAGGATAAAGGATCAAAGGATTTGAAAAGGATAAAGGATCACGAAAGGATAAAAGGATTGGCAAAGGATGAAAAGGATGAAAGGATAAGCCCTCCAAAGGAT

AAAGGATAA

ATTCAAATACTTCAAATAGTCAAATATCAAATATGCTTCAAATATCAAATATCGGTCAAATAAGTCAAATAAGTCAAATATCAAATATCAAATACTCAAATATCAAATAGTGTCAAATACGAATTGGGTCAAATATCAAATATGTGTTCAAATATTCTTCAAATACTGGACACTCAAATAGGAGTCAAATATCAAATATCAAATACGTGAAGTGCTTGTCAAATATTTCAAATACTTTCAAATATTCAAATACTCAAATATGTTCAAATATCAAATATCAAATATTTCAAATATCAAATATCAAATAGTCCTCAAATAGCAAACCAGTCAAATATCAAATATGTCAAATATGCTCACGGCAACCTCAAATATCAAATATCAAATAGATGTCAAATAAGTTTCAAATATCAAATATCAAATATCAAATATCAAATATTCAAATATCAAATAGCGGGCTCAAATAAGCTCAAATACGTCAAATAGGGGGTCAAATAGATCAAATAGTCAAATATTCAAATACATCAAATAGTCAAATACAAGAACCACCGAGATCTCAAATAATCAAATATCAAATATGGTCAAATAAATATTCAAATAGGTCAAATAAGATCAAATATCAAATAAGTCGTCCATCAAATAGTCAAATAGCTCAAATAACCTCAAATATCAAATATTCAAATACCGGTCATCAAATAGGACAAATCAAATAGTCAAATAAGATCCTCTCAAATAATTCAAATAGCTGTTCAAATACTCAAATATCAAATAGTCAAATATCAAATATTCAAATATCAAATACTTCAAATATGTTCAAATAATCAAATACTCAAATATCAAATAATCAAATAATACTTCAAATATACCAAACGCTCAAATATTAGTTGGATCAAATATCTTCAAATATCAAATAA

TCAAATATC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This simple code will resolve you problem, so the program read file and put every line in list I filtered the list, because I need to remove '\n' and after I run a loop and check the index of every item. if index is pair then is s and t will equal the value of the next item.

```
f = open('test.txt', 'r')
all = list(filter(lambda a: a != '\n', f.readlines()))

for idx, val in enumerate(all):
    if idx % 2 == 0:
        s=val.rstrip()
        t=all[idx + 1].rstrip()
        BruteForce(s, t)
```